# Why my nasm code doesn't do anything when executed?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1035362/Simple-Window-With-Assembly) to create a window on Windows SO with NASM.
I downloaded the code from the page and I did some modifications to portable the code to 64 bits, like changing the usage of `dword` to `qword`, changing the usages of 32 bits registers to 64 bits registers, and changing the usages of `dd` in `.data` section to `dq`.

After the modifications I compiled my code using the following commands:

```
nasm -f win64 window.asm
gcc window.obj -o window.exe
```

Everything seems to be alright. No errors. But when I execute the `window.exe` file, nothing happens.

Did I do something wrong? I already tried to do some other study-cases with NASM, and all of them don't do anything when I execute the `.exe` file.

In the following lines, I'll let my current code.

```
;%include "nagoa+.inc"

extern printf
extern ExitProcess

extern RegisterClassExA
extern CreateWindowExA
extern MessageBoxA
extern GetModuleHandleA
extern PeekMessageA
extern TranslateMessage
extern DispatchMessageA
extern PostQuitMessage
extern DefWindowProcA
extern ShowWindow
extern UpdateWindow
extern GetStockObject
extern BeginPaint
extern EndPaint
extern Rectangle
extern Ellipse
extern MoveToEx
extern LineTo
extern DrawTextA
extern SetBkMode
extern SetTextColor
extern CreateSolidBrush
extern CreatePen
extern SelectObject
extern DeleteObject
extern LoadIconA
extern LoadCursorA

%define WS_OVERLAPPED       0x00000000
%define WS_POPUP            0x80000000
%define WS_CHILD            0x40000000
%define WS_MINIMIZE         0x20000000
%define WS_VISIBLE          0x10000000
%define WS_DISABLED         0x08000000
%define WS_CLIPSIBLINGS     0x04000000
%define WS_CLIPCHILDREN     0x02000000
%define WS_MAXIMIZE         0x01000000
%define WS_CAPTION          0x00C00000
%define WS_BORDER           0x00800000
%define WS_DLGFRAME         0x00400000
%define WS_VSCROLL          0x00200000
%define WS_HSCROLL          0x00100000
%define WS_SYSMENU          0x00080000
%define WS_THICKFRAME       0x00040000
%define WS_GROUP            0x00020000
%define WS_TABSTOP          0x00010000

%define WS_MINIMIZEBOX      0x00020000
%define WS_MAXIMIZEBOX      0x00010000

%define WS_TILED            WS_OVERLAPPED
%define WS_ICONIC           WS_MINIMIZE
%define WS_SIZEBOX          WS_THICKFRAME
%define WS_TILEDWINDOW      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW

; Common Window Styles 

%define WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW (WS_OVERLAPPED     | \
                             WS_CAPTION        | \
                             WS_SYSMENU        | \
                             WS_THICKFRAME     | \
                             WS_MINIMIZEBOX    | \
                             WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
                         
%define PM_REMOVE 1h

%define WM_QUIT                         0x0012
%define WM_PAINT                        0x000F
%define WM_CLOSE                        0x0010

; Class styles 

%define CS_VREDRAW          0x0001
%define CS_HREDRAW          0x0002
%define CS_DBLCLKS          0x0008
%define CS_OWNDC            0x0020
%define CS_CLASSDC          0x0040
%define CS_PARENTDC         0x0080
%define CS_NOCLOSE          0x0200
%define CS_SAVEBITS         0x0800
%define CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT  0x1000
%define CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW  0x2000
%define CS_GLOBALCLASS      0x4000

; Standard Icon IDs 

%define IDI_APPLICATION     32512
%define IDC_ARROW 32512

;Data section of the KoolB app

section .data

Windowclassname db 'MyClass', 0
Windowname db 'My Window', 0
string_reg_failed  db 'Failed to register main window', 0

Instance dq 0
Windowhandle dq 0

section .bss

; This is my way!
MessageBuffer resb 28
OurWindowclass resb 48

section .text
global main

main:
    push 0
    call GetModuleHandleA
    mov qword [Instance], rax

    ; Fill all the OurWindowclass structure members ( dword[OurWindowclass+?] where '?' is member offset )
    mov qword[OurWindowclass], 48 ; .cbSize
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+4], CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW 
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+8], WindowProc ; lpfnWndProc
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+12], 0
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+16], 0

    mov rax, qword[Instance]
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+20], rax ; .hInstance

    push IDI_APPLICATION
    push 0
    call LoadIconA
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+24], rax ; .hIcon

    push IDI_APPLICATION
    push 0
    call LoadCursorA
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+28], rax ; .hCursor

    mov qword[OurWindowclass+32], 5 ; .hbrBackground, 5 is COLOR_WINDOW
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+36], 0 ; .lpszMenuName
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+40], Windowclassname ; .lpszClassName
    mov qword[OurWindowclass+44], 0 ; .hIconSm

    ; Now register our class
    lea rax, [OurWindowclass]
    push rax
    call RegisterClassExA

    ; If return value is not zero then create the main window
    cmp eax, 0
    jne Lcreate

    push 0       ; button type - supposed to be 0,
    push Windowname    ; but I need all the help I can get :)
    push string_reg_failed
    push 0         ; our "handle", I think
    call MessageBoxA

    ; Oops!
    jmp exit

Lcreate:
    ; Call the 'CreateWindowExA' function to create the main window
    push 0
    push qword[Instance]
    push 0
    push 0
    push 362    ; Height
    push 362    ; Width
    push 140    ; Top
    push 360    ; Left
    push WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
    push Windowname
    push Windowclassname
    push 0
    call CreateWindowExA

    mov dword[Windowhandle], eax

    ; Show the main window
    push 1                  ; 1 is SW_SHOW
    push qword[Windowhandle]
    call ShowWindow

    push qword[Windowhandle]
    call UpdateWindow

    ;Lb1:
    ;jmp Lb1

    ; -- every time user moves mouse or imput some msg this loop is activated
    ; -- in order to get all messages imputed by the user 
messloop:

    push PM_REMOVE
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push MessageBuffer
    call PeekMessageA

    ; See if the return value is zero
    cmp rax, 0
    je nextloop
    
    ; If the 'message' is WM_QUIT then we have to QUIT!
    cmp qword[MessageBuffer+4], WM_QUIT
    je exit

    push MessageBuffer
    call TranslateMessage

    push MessageBuffer
    call DispatchMessageA

nextloop:
    jmp near messloop

exit:
    push qword 0
    call ExitProcess

    ret

global WindowProc
WindowProc:
    push rbp    ; Saves the base pointer
    mov rbp, rsp    ; Saves the stack pointer

    ; Here is our parameters

        ; dword[ebp+20] ; LPARAM
    
        ; dword[ebp+16] ; WPARAM
    
        ; dword[ebp+12] ; Msg
    
        ; dword[ebp+8]  ; hWnd

    ; case WM_CLOSE
    cmp qword[rbp+12], WM_CLOSE
    jne Ldefault
    ;{  begin WM_CLOSE
    push 0
    call PostQuitMessage
    ;}  end WM_CLOSE

Ldefault:
    push qword[ebp+20]  ; LPARAM
    push qword[ebp+16]  ; WPARAM
    push qword[ebp+12]  ; Msg
    push qword[ebp+8]   ; hWnd
    call DefWindowProcA

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: you have changed code from 32 bits to 64 bits, and under 64bits, The windows calling conversion is different from 32 bits. check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170

Comment: Fastcall convention used by Win64 is rather complicated,; in assembly language it's easier to use a [macro](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winabi.htm#WinABI). For example see [skelet64](https://euroassembler.eu/prowin64/skelet64.htm).

Comment: If you're just learning assembly language, or just learning how to write Windows programs in assembly language, I strongly suggest that you either study 32-bit assembly or 64-bit. Don't try, at least not until you have a firm grasp of both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows assembly language, trying to convert a 32-bit assembly language program to 64 bits.

Comment: ^^ don't try to port a tutorial to another OS or architecture when you're still just learning the basic thing the tutorial is teaching you.  Find a tutorial for the flavour of asm you want to use, e.g. NASM syntax for 64-bit x86-64 code for Windows.